# PHP code to extract column names and alias names in a complex mysql query

Tags: php, regex, mysqli

I have a select query in PHP program.

```
SELECT u.name AS name,
    u.email AS email,
    u.status AS status ,
    u.is_blocked AS is_blocked,         
    pm.plan_name AS plan_name,
    upt.amount AS amount,
    upt.payment_status AS payment_status,
    DATE_FORMAT(upt.dt, '%m-%d-%Y')AS payment_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(upt.plan_expiry_date,'%m-%d-%Y') AS exp_dt
FROM users u, user_plan_transaction upt, plan_master pm
WHERE
    u.user_id = upt.user_id
    AND upt.payment_status  IN ('PAID', 'ADMIN_PAID')
    AND upt.dt = (SELECT dt FROM user_plan_transaction WHERE user_id = u.user_id
                  ORDER BY dt DESC
                  LIMIT 1 )
    AND upt.plan_id = pm.plan_id
```

From this query i need to extract two data sets:
 (Both the data sets are column names as below:)

```
(1) u.name, u.email, u.status, u.is_blocked, pm.plan_name, upt.amount, upt.payment_status, 
DATE_FORMAT(upt.dt, '%m-%d-%Y'),  DATE_FORMAT(upt.plan_expiry_date,'%m-%d-%Y')
(2) name, email, status, is_blocked, plan_name, amount, payment_status, payment_date, exp_dt
```

I tried to do it with `mysqli_fetch_field()` function.
But the function does not return values `DATE_FORMAT(upt.dt, '%m-%d-%Y')` and `DATE_FORMAT(upt.plan_expiry_date,'%m-%d-%Y')` in the dataset

Also if the query changes later I want to be again able to extract the fields.

Eg. Query 2:

```
SELECT name,
       email,
       status,
       is_blocked
FROM users
```

Then I need the two data sets to be:

```
(1) name, email, status, is_blocked
(2) name, email, status, is_blocked
```

I need to extract these 2 datasets for any mysql query.

Could anyone help please.

Thanks

I cannot find a mysql php based solution.. Do i have to go with regex to solve this problem?
How do I preg_split by a comma which is not in bracket. Eg:
 DATE_FORMAT(upt.dt, '%m-%d-%Y')AS payment_date,
I do not want to split by the comma after "upt.dt" but with the comma at the end after "payment_date".